# dyld: Library not loaded:...DJIWidget

Tags: objective-c, dji-sdk

**Description**

DJI-SDK **dyld: Library not loaded:**

The Xcode console message:

```
dyld: Library not loaded:...DJIWidget
  Referenced from: /private/.../DJIUXSDK.framework/DJIUXSDK
  Reason: image not found
```

**Environment**

Create a new project and create a `Podfile`, nothing else had been added. (objc + Xcode 10.1)

The `Podfile` is show below:

```
platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'DJISDK4.9' do
    pod 'DJI-SDK-iOS'
    pod 'DJI-UXSDK-iOS'
    pod 'DJIWidget'
end
```

> even if I set the specific version of DJISDK (4.9.1) and UXSDK (4.9), the project still aborted for the same problem.

**Already Tried**

The following does not work for my problem.

X 1. clean and rebuild

X 2. run on the device instead of  the simulator

X 3. Add Framework:`FFMpeg` from `DJIWidget` to `Linked Frameworks and Libraries`

**Source Code**

Did nothing to the project. I just create a new single view app project in Xcode.

And create a `Podfile` and add frameworks. Nothing else has been added or modified.

Comment: Have you tried adding the missing DJIWidget to "Embed Frameworks" phase in the "Build Phases"?

Comment: @edopelawi I'd tried to do that, however; there is no DJIWidget.framework. I posted my project on github, here is the link: https://github.com/UnknownWarning/DJISDK4.9